# an error occurred while registering or adding a user

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa

what could be the mistake? I send json with login, password and mailing address.
The database is present. I am sending a user to register, must first be checked for its presence in the database. Writes that the password cannot be zero. Tell me, what are the options?
If you need more information, please let me know.

UPDATE ERROR:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.coooo.springboot.model.User.setUsername(String)" because "users" is null
    at com.coooo.springboot.service.JwtUserService.register(JwtUserService.java:121) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.coooo.springboot.controller.UserAuthenticationController.registerUser(UserAuthenticationController.java:88) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
```

JSON Request:

```
{"username":"jeffry",
"email":"Red@mail.ru",
"password":"1a234567890"}
```

RESPONE:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-07-03T18:48:42.872+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/auth/signup"
}
```

ENTITY:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usr",

uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "phone")
})
public class User extends BaseEntity  {
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Username cannot be empty")
    @Size(min=3, message="min 3 characters")
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name = "secondName")
    private String secondName;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Password cannot be empty")
    @Size(min=8, message="min 8 characters")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @Email(message = "Email is not correct")
    @NotBlank(message = "Email cannot be empty")
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;
    
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setSecondName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

UPDATE SERVICE REGISTRATION METHOD:

```
  public ResponseEntity<?> register(JwtUser user) {
        
        User users = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
        User emails = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
     if(users != null && emails !=null) {
         return ResponseEntity
            .badRequest()
            .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username or email is exist"));
            
        }
    
               
        users.setUsername(user.getUsername()); 
        users.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        users.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));
        users.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        users.setActive(true);
      
        userRepository.save(users);
        
       

        return new ResponseEntity<>("User Created!", HttpStatus.OK);
    
    
    }
```

CONFIG:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    
    private static final String LOGIN_ENDPOINT = "/auth/**";
    
     @Autowired
     private  JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
     
       @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
       }
     
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http 
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(LOGIN_ENDPOINT).permitAll()       
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
        
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
    @Service
    public class JwtUserService implements UserDetailsService{
        
        
        private UserRepository userRepository;
        
        private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
        
          @Autowired
            public JwtUserService(UserRepository userRepository,  BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
                this.userRepository = userRepository;        
                this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
          }
//todo
public User register(User user){code} 
    //todo
    }
```

UPDATE class JwtToken:

```
public class JwtUser implements UserDetails {
    
    private String token;

    private  Long id;
    
    private  String username;

    private  String secondName;
    
    private  String password;
    
    private  String phone;
    
    private  String description;
    
    private  String email;

    private  boolean active;
    
    private  Date lastPasswordResetDate;

    private  Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    
    
    public JwtUser(Long id, String username, String secondName, String password, String phone, String description,
            String email, boolean active, Date lastPasswordResetDate,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.secondName = companyName;
        this.password = password;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.description = description;
        this.email = email;
        this.active = active;
        this.lastPasswordResetDate = lastPasswordResetDate;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }
    
    
    
    public JwtUser(String token, Long id, String username, String secondName,  String phone, String description,
            String email, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.token=token;
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.secondName = companyName;      
        this.phone = phone;
        this.description = description;
        this.email = email;     
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }
    

    public JwtUser(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities,
            String email, boolean active) {
                
        this.username = username;
        this.password=password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
        this.email = email;     
        this.active=active;
        
    }
    
    public JwtUser(){
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @JsonIgnore 
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    public Date getLastPasswordResetDate() {
        return lastPasswordResetDate;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        
        return authorities;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username=username;
    }
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        
        return true;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        
        return true;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: somewhere in your code, I think some constructor with no-args.

Comment: @newuserua_ext updated the post. the service has such a constructor.
What else should you pay attention to?

Comment: Where is the rawPassword parameter? I don't see it, I only see the User.password with the annotations stating that password may not be empty; however, the error message complains on rawPassword cannot be null. Find where rawPassword is set, and there you have the issue.

Comment: @bichoFlyer I myself do not know where this parameter comes from, I did not announce it.  I changed the code a little, now this error: User.setUsername(String)" because "users" is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got it:

```
    if(users!=null) {
            
            return null;
            
    }
```

You are returning null if the find user returns a value, but if find user returns null you are trying to set password on null. Change those null checking for: `if(users==null)` and `if(emails==null)` Also delete the supress warnings, since the compiler was warning right about null references.

Comment: but how it turns out. I accept json for the user (with username, email, password), if there is something in the database (not noll), then he should not set these parameters. Otherwise, take these parameters from json and set them (send to the database).   "ps I also forgot to put the return when checking the user"

Comment: ok, in such case, you need to initialize the users variable to a non null value after checking. So, instead of changing your if condition, add `users = new User();` just before users.setUsername... and the same for emails. What happens is that if you're getting null, you need to set a valid value. I'd use an Optional here, that would make things easier.